# SQL Login and access

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with `SQL`.

- I installed a fresh version of SQL 2012,
- On the creation part I assign a `user` to be `Kleber-Pc`, accessed couple times fine.
- However when I tried to access it from my **asp.net mvc application using windows credentials**, the SQL rejected the connection, so I tried to load SQL and its not allowing me to connected it.

The first image below show the login box

[image]

The image below show what it results when **clicked** on **connect**.

[image]

So my questions are:

- How can I access SQL?
- How can I set up user/password that I can use in my application (instead use windows authentication)?

**Obs.:**

I didn't create a user account or password for SQL that I remember; I am using `Visual Studio 2012` on `windows 8` machine.

I searched online and could not find anything related, I am not expert on SQL, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.install_upgrade.doc/install/t_cr_sql_logins_05.htm

Comment: http://www.katieandemil.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user

Comment: have your problem solved bro??

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for delay in replyto you, have been off for few weeks due to birth of my daughter. Yes I fixed the problem by opening the sql installation tool, using the install option, I created new sql instance, added new instance name, username and login. When the setup was done, opened the sql management studio with new credentials and voala, once inside the sql I updated the users and passwords. In my app I am using new instance name to connected to sql, works perfect. Thanks for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1** -  **Mixed Authentication Mode**

## [SQL Server : Step by step installation guide for SQL Server 2012](http://sivasqlbi.blogspot.com/2012/03/sql-server-step-by-step-installation.html)

## [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WTVLo9kvK3w)

If you are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication, verify that SQL Server is configured in **Mixed Authentication Mode** and verify that SQL Server login exists and that you have spelled it properly.

If you are trying to connect using Windows Authentication, verify that you are properly logged into the correct domain.

It’s probably because UAC. Try right clicking and running as administrator and seeing if it goes away.

**OR**

SQL Authentication not enabled: If you use SQL Login for the first time on SQL Server instance than very often error 18456 occurs because Windows Authentication (only) is set in Server properties (security section).

To Access Server Properties, Open SSMS, go to Object Explorer pane (use view if you can't see it). Use the connect button to connect to database engine for your server. Once connected you will see it in object explorer. Right click server and click properties. Server Properties window will appear.

[image]

microsoft sql server error 18456 login failed for user server properties

See below screenshot that might be causing SQL login to fail

[image]

18456 windows authentication
You should set Server Authentication to SQL Server Windows Authentication Mode (see below). Once you select SQL Server Authentication you have to restart the server.

[image]

**18456 sql authentication**

**Restart required:** You have to restart the service when you change server authentication but bear in mind if someone hasn't restart the service this might be the reason why you get 18456. Remember service restart should be carefully planned on production servers as it will clear certain information (cache) and may impact performance of the server.

**NOTE:** I recently tried to restart service using SSMS 2012 on Windows 7 and it didn't work.... actually the message below was hidden behind SSMS window and I just did not see it so ensure you get this message when you decide to restart the service.

18456 restart required

[image]

**Invalid userID:** SQL Server is not able to find the specified UserID on the server you are trying to get. The most common cause is that this userID hasn’t been granted access on the server but this could be also a simple typo or you accidentally are trying to connect to different server (Typical if you use more than one server)

**Invalid password:** Wrong password or just a typo. Remember that this username can have different passwords on different servers.

**less common errors:** The userID might be disabled on the server. Windows login was provided for SQL Authentication (change to Windows Authentication. If you use SSMS you might have to run as different user to use this option). Password might have expired and probably several other reasons…

**18456 state 1 explanations:** Usually Microsoft SQL Server will give you error state 1 which actually does not mean anything apart from that you have 18456 error. State 1 is used to hide actual state in order to protect the system, which to me makes sense. Below is a list with all different states and for more information about retrieving accurate states visit **[Understanding "login failed" (Error 18456) error messages in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)**

```
ERROR STATE       ERROR DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 and 5           Invalid userid
6                 Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7                 Login disabled and password mismatch
8                 Password mismatch
9                 Invalid password
11 and 12         Valid login but server access failure
13                SQL Server service paused
18                Change password required
```

**[Source](http://www.katieandemil.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user)**

## [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=aU8RhjdkCoE)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however when I open SQL, then go to object explorer it does not allow me to connect. So I cant go to properties.

Comment: Why dont you to try the other methods

Comment: @KleberBH _I didn't create a user account or password for SQL that I remember_ so it is better to **re-install** it again from the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed SQL did you set kleber-pc as a SQL user? If not the user will be 'sa' you will have been prompted to enter an sa password.

If you can't remember the password you'll most likely have to re-install the instance.

Once you are logged in (with an appropriate account) you will be able to add/edit user accounts as you wish.